# syntax/logic errors in port map

Tags: compiler-errors, vhdl

For this code:

```
architecture sm1 of SubModule is

component ME
    port
    (
        bN      : in integer;
        eP      : in integer;
        mD      : in integer;
        CLK     : in std_logic;
        RDY     : out std_logic;
        result  : out integer
    );
end component;

...

begin   

PROCESS_1: process (N, j, CLK)
    type State_type is (ReadState, ExecPhase1State, ExecPhase2State, OperateMEState, WaitForMEState, WaitForOtherProcessState);
    variable State : State_Type;
    ...
    variable denum : integer;
    variable num : integer;
    variable ep : integer;
    variable MERdy : std_logic;

begin
    if rising_edge(CLK) then
        if State = ReadState then
            ...

        elsif State = ExecPhase1State then          
            ...

        elsif State = OperateMEState then
            State := WaitForMEState;
            ME_1: ME port map 
            (
                bN => 16, 
                eP => ep, 
                mD => denum, 
                CLK => CLK, 
                RDY => MERdy, 
                result => num
            );

        elsif State = WaitForMEState then
            if MERdy = "1" then
                MERdy <= "0";
                State := ExecPhase2State;
            end if;

        elsif State = ExecPhase2State then
            ...

        elsif State = WaitForOtherProcessState then
            if rdy_2 = "1" then
                State := ReadState;
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

...

end sm1;
```

the compiler generates the following two errors:
 near text "port";  expecting "(", or "'", or "."
 near text ";";  expecting ":=", or "<="

Note that both are related to the port map segment (the second one referring to the ";" of ME_1: ME port map (...);)

I tried without "full signal mapping" also, i.e. instead of "bN => 16," just "16,", although this shouldn't make any difference, and got the same errors. The most confusing part for me is that these errors indicate bad syntax, however, I checked various sources for port map syntax, and found no differences. Where lies my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Realise that VHDL is essentially two different languages in one.

Outside of a process, it is a parallel processing language, with one set of permitted constructs to create and interconnect multiple processes. It operates rather like a dataflow language, and has something in common with functional-programming languages like Haskell.

Inside a process, it is a sequential language, like Ada or C, with the usual selection of statements, expressions, loops, and abstractions like functions and procedures (which C calls void functions).

You are trying to write Haskell in the middle of a C program ... not going to work.

ME is a component : this is an abstraction over a separate process (or set of processes).

Either re-create the functionality of "ME" as a procedure (which would be legal here), or instantiate it as a separate component OUTSIDE the process, and learn how to use signals (the inter-process communication mechanism) to connect ME to your main process.

For example if there is an "Enable" input to ME, you can drive that to '1' in the relevant state, and '0' in other states, and wait until a "Done" signal from ME is '1' before moving to the next state.

Answer (score 1):

The code has a `ME` module instantiation inside a process at `ME_1: ME port map`, which is illegal since module instantiation is a concurrent statement, so it only goes outside a process.

Comment: I see. Is there a workaround? I mean, the ME module is used inside the process in (almost) every iteration, if it is to be outside the process, I need a way to synchronize it with the results inside.

Comment: The last section in the answer from Brian Drummond elaborates on the issue.