# Having a VHDL component syntax error. the problem is with Adder_4bit during IF statements. Previous components work fine. (with entire code this time)

Tags: syntax, components, vhdl

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity F_A is
  port(
        a,b,c_in : in std_logic;
        sum,c_out : out std_logic);
end F_A;

architecture behave of F_A is
begin 
  sum <= a xor b xor c_in;
  c_out <= (a and b)or(a and c_in)or(b and c_in);
end behave;


library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Adder_4bit is
  port( a,b: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        Cin: in std_logic;
        sum: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        Cout: out std_logic);
end Adder_4bit;

architecture logic of Adder_4bit is
   signal c : std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
   component F_A
      port( a,b,c_in : in std_logic;
            sum,c_out: out std_logic);
   end component;
   begin
     FA0 : F_A 
           port map(a(0),b(0),Cin,sum(0),c(0));
     FA1 : F_A 
           port map(a(1),b(1),c(0),sum(1),c(1));
     FA2 : F_A 
           port map(a(2),b(2),c(1),sum(2),c(2));
     FA3 : F_A 
           port map(a(3),b(3),c(2),sum(3), Cout);
end logic;

Library IEEE;
USE IEEE.Std_logic_1164.all;

entity Dff is 
   port(
      Q : out std_logic;    
      Clk :in std_logic;  
   signal sync_reset: in std_logic;  
      D :in  std_logic    
   );
end Dff;

architecture Behavioral of Dff is  
begin  
 process(Clk)
 begin 
    if(rising_edge(Clk)) then
   if(sync_reset='1') then 
    Q <= '0';
   else 
    Q <= D; 
   end if;
    end if;       
 end process;  
end Behavioral; 


library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity proj1 is
port( A, B, Ac, Bc: in STD_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        C: out STD_LOGIC_vector(3 downto 0):= "0000";
        signal sync_reset: in std_logic;
        s1,s2,ci: in STD_logic;
        co : out STD_logic := '0');
end proj1;

architecture behavioral of proj1 is

Component Adder_4bit is
    port( a,b: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        Cin: in std_logic;
        sum: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        Cout: out std_logic);
end component;

Component Dff is
   port(
      Q : out std_logic;    
      Clk :in std_logic;  
   signal sync_reset: in std_logic;  
      D :in  std_logic    
   );
end component;
begin
Dff0 : Dff 
           port map(A(0),clk, sync_reset, A(0));
Dff1 : Dff 
           port map(A(1),clk, sync_reset, A(1)); 
Dff2 : Dff 
           port map(A(2),clk, sync_reset, A(2)); 
Dff3 : Dff 
           port map(A(3),clk, sync_reset, A(3)); 
Dff4 : Dff 
           port map(B(0),clk, sync_reset, B(0)); 
Dff5 : Dff 
           port map(B(1),clk, sync_reset, B(1)); 
Dff6 : Dff 
           port map(B(2),clk, sync_reset, B(2)); 
Dff7 : Dff 
           port map(B(3),clk, sync_reset, B(3)); 
Dff8 : Dff 
           port map(s1,clk, sync_reset, s1); 
Dff9 : Dff 
           port map(s2,clk, sync_reset, s2); 
Dff10 : Dff 
           port map(ci,clk, sync_reset, ci);
             
             

process (ALU)
BEGIN
          
IF s2 = '0' and s1 = '0' and ci = '0' then
C(0)<=A(0);
C(1)<=A(1);
C(2)<=A(2);
C(3)<=A(3);
elsif  s2 = '0' and s1 = '0' and ci = '1' then
adder0 : Adder_4bit 
        port map(A, "0001",Cin, C, Co); 

elsif  s2 = '0' and s1 = '1' and ci = '0' then
    
adder1 : Adder_4bit 
        port map(A, B,Cin, C, Co);

elsif  s2 = '0' and s1 = '1' and ci = '1' then

adder2 : Adder_4bit 
        port map(A, B,Cin, Ac, Co);
        
adder3 : Adder_4bit 
        port map(Ac, "0001",Cin, C, Co);
        
elsif  s2 = '1' and s1 = '0' and ci = '0' then

adder4 : Adder_4bit 
        port map(B, "1111",Cin, Bc, Co);
        
adder5 : Adder_4bit 
        port map(Bc Xor "1111" , "0001",Cin, Bc, Co);
        
adder6 : Adder_4bit 
        port map(A ,Bc ,Cin , C, Co);
        
elsif s2 = '1' and s1 = '0' and ci = '1' then
        
adder7 : Adder_4bit 
        port map(B Xor "1111" , "0001",Cin, Bc, Co);

adder8 : Adder_4bit 
        port map(A, Bc,Cin, Bc, Co);
    
elsif s2 = '1' and s1 = '1' then
      C (0) <= A(0) Xor B(0);
      C (1) <= A(1) Xor B(1);
      C (2) <= A(2) Xor B(2);
      C (3) <= A(3) Xor B(3);

end if;
end process;
end behavioral;
```

The errors are as follows:

```
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at proj1.vhd(135) near text "port";  expecting "(", or "'", or "."
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at proj1.vhd(135) near text ";";  expecting ":=", or "<="
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at proj1.vhd(140) near text "port";  expecting "(", or "'", or "."
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at proj1.vhd(140) near text ";";  expecting ":=", or "<="
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at proj1.vhd(145) near text "port";  expecting "(", or "'", or "."
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at proj1.vhd(145) near text ";";  expecting ":=", or "<="
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at proj1.vhd(148) near text "port";  expecting "(", or "'", or "."
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at proj1.vhd(148) near text ";";  expecting ":=", or "<="
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at proj1.vhd(153) near text "port";  expecting "(", or "'", or "."
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at proj1.vhd(153) near text ";";  expecting ":=", or "<="
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at proj1.vhd(156) near text "port";  expecting "(", or "'", or "."
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at proj1.vhd(156) near text ";";  expecting ":=", or "<="
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at proj1.vhd(159) near text "port";  expecting "(", or "'", or "."
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at proj1.vhd(159) near text ";";  expecting ":=", or "<="
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at proj1.vhd(164) near text "port";  expecting "(", or "'", or "."
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at proj1.vhd(164) near text ";";  expecting ":=", or "<="
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at proj1.vhd(167) near text "port";  expecting "(", or "'", or "."
Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at proj1.vhd(167) near text ";";  expecting ":=", or "<="
```

And if it it is relevant and you have any assistance for my general project the goal is

```
S2 S1 Ci
0  0  0  => C=A
0  0  1  => C=A+1
0  1  0  => C=A+B
0  1  1  => C=A+B+1
1  0  0  => C=A-B-1
1  0  1  => C=A-B
1  1  N/A  => C=A XOR B
```

The idea is that It uses D-flip flops to check if the inputs/output are valid. I also was hoping to get double checked that using the component with declared output variables in the process just directly sets them to the output value from the component. Because of some of the snippets I used from the internet it's still Vague to me. Very new to VHDL literally started using it less then 1 month ago. any advice appreciated!

Comment: As @user_181883 alluded in a comment to the predecessor question component instantiations aren't subprogram calls, a component instantiation represents a part of the design hierarchy (hardware). The architecture statement part contains concurrent statements while a process statement contains only sequential statements describing behavior. and component instances are concurrent statements. Control flow values on formal input port signals, hierarchy can't be conditionally 'present'.

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22113991/syntax-logic-errors-in-port-map/22114766#22114766 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251164/vhdl-multipliers/15251764#15251764 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196987/vhdl-process-if-then-else-if-statement/19197489#19197489

Answer (score -2):

The conditional component instantiation is ambiguous.

```
  ...
elsif  s2 = '0' and s1 = '0' and ci = '1' then
adder0 : Adder_4bit 
        port map(A, "0001",Cin, C, Co); 

elsif  s2 = '0' and s1 = '1' and ci = '0' then
    
adder1 : Adder_4bit 
        port map(A, B,Cin, C, Co);

elsif  s2 = '0' and s1 = '1' and ci = '1' then

adder2 : Adder_4bit 
        port map(A, B,Cin, Ac, Co);
        
adder3 : Adder_4bit 
        port map(Ac, "0001",Cin, C, Co);
        
elsif  s2 = '1' and s1 = '0' and ci = '0' then

adder4 : Adder_4bit 
        port map(B, "1111",Cin, Bc, Co);
        
adder5 : Adder_4bit 
        port map(Bc Xor "1111" , "0001",Cin, Bc, Co);
        
adder6 : Adder_4bit 
        port map(A ,Bc ,Cin , C, Co);
        
elsif s2 = '1' and s1 = '0' and ci = '1' then
        
adder7 : Adder_4bit 
        port map(B Xor "1111" , "0001",Cin, Bc, Co);

adder8 : Adder_4bit 
        port map(A, Bc,Cin, Bc, Co);
...
```

You can instantiate the component concurrently out of condition, and assign conditional inputs for the component so as to get the right output.

Feel free to ask me any questions.

Comment: how do I " instantiate the component concurrently out of condition" I honestly don't even know what that means.

Comment: This answer makes little sense. Components cannot be instantiated inside a process. They can only be instantiated inside an architecture. Generates may be used to conditionally instantiate components at elaboration time. Inputs cannot be connected "conditionally".

Comment: Taking an instance from a component means physically creating a copy of the component in the design. In other words, this happens at the moment of synthesis, not at runtime. Therefore, component  instantiation can not occur under signal conditions at runtime.